# Change object's layer dynamically in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, layer

I need to do something like "Move up", "Move down" with the objects on my GRID from C# code while executing, is there any possibilities?

Comment: Can you go further with your explanation?

Comment: Oh, sorry, no problems... For example, I have two controls on my GRID, which overlaps... And I need to move bottom control to the front from C# code... Ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
private bool _isUp = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (_isUp) {
        Canvas.SetZIndex(rectangle1, 1);
    } else {
        Canvas.SetZIndex(rectangle1, 0);
    }

    _isUp = !_isUp;
}
```

I just use 2 rectangles in my sample, for this.

```
    <Rectangle Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,142,0,0" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Fill="#FF9D2A2A" />
    <Rectangle Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,120,0,0" Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Fill="#FF265D80" />
```