# wpf C# change layer position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have XML code like this:

```
<rectangle />
<textbox />
<button Name="PositionChanger" />
```

If the button with name *PositionChanger* is clicked, the rectangle should move in front of the TextBox and the TextBox behind the rectangle.

Please help me to create it programically using C#.

Comment: Please give a clear view to help us in answering

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092836/change-objects-layer-dynamically-in-wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Zindex` property to achieve this.

```
//initially text box would be on top because Zindex is set to 1 and Rectangle would be behind it
<TextBox x:Name="text" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Panel.ZIndex="0"/>
```

Inside button click event do this

```
  Panel.SetZIndex(text, 0);
  Panel.SetZIndex(rect,1);
```

now rectangle would be on top and textbox would be behind rectangle